# Query Returning the Wrong Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a login/logout app for my team,

I want to get the last logout time for every day (knowing that the employee can logout and login again during the day)

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(time, "%d.%m.%Y"), 
  DATE_FORMAT(time, "%H:%i:%s") 
FROM 
  mk_pay_loginout 
WHERE 
  u_id = ' . $u_id . ' 
  AND type = 2 
  AND time LIKE "' . $this_month . '-%" 
GROUP BY 
  DAY(time) 
ORDER BY 
  time DESC
```

`type = 2` means logout when `type = 1` means login

Using this code I found out that the script is not picking the last logout of the day

Here is an example:

[image]

For `2021-08-24` he logged out during the day then logged in again then logout.

The query I'm using should pickup only that of `2021-08-24 18:00:04` but here it's picking the wrong one that of `2021-08-24 11:11:30`

[image]

Now can anyone help me find the error in the query?

Comment: Echo your query to see if the time query is correct. Show it here as well, if it looks correct to you.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group by doesn't group on date but day, and you haven't picked up max time for the given date group. Rerun your query as given below.

```
select
    date(t1.time) as date,
    max(time(t1.time)) as latest_time
from
    t1
where
    year(t1.time) = 2021
    and month(t1.time) = 8
    and t1.type = 2
group by
    date(t1.time)
order by
    date(t1.time);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7e4e379b5a87b5afc3be5c3d41d40661)